# Cant Override Bundle Product Xml on Custom Theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, bundle-product

I have a custom theme in Magento 2.1.7 and I want to override the bundle product xml. I have created the xml in my theme in the following path

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_name}/{theme_name}/Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

I have added a line to remove the breadcrumbs but it won't work. The same line although work great if I put it in the same xml in the vendor/magento/module-bundle folder.

I have cleared cache but the problem persists.